# How do I search for a bone's name, then rename it with a script?

Tags: python, scripting, armature, bones

What I need to do is search for a bone then rename that bone, for example I want to find the left hand. I search for that bone with the letters "hand", "ik", and "L" in it (caps don't matter). Then I basically want to rename that bone to a pre-determined name. I've tried this code and it works for bones I already have the name of:

```
import bpy

bones_list = bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones

for item in bones_list:
    item.name=item.name.replace("OldName","NewName")
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems more of a Python question as you seem to have all the Blender pieces already figured...

```py
import bpy

bones_list = bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones

for item in bones_list:
    name = item.name.lower()
    if "hand" not in name: continue
    if "ik" not in name: continue
    if "l" not in name: continue
    item.name = "RENAMED"
    break
```

I programmed it the way you described your problem, but I have a strong suspicion this is not what you wanted...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://www.python.org/ and https://www.w3schools.com/python/ for resources for learning Python.

In the for loop you are using in the script you go through all bones in your armature one by one so what you replace with the .replace() function will be done for all names, so you can just do that. If you need the name to meet some conditions you can use [if  statements](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

```
import bpy

bones_list = bpy.data.armatures['Armature'].bones

for item in bones_list:
    if all(words in item.name for words in ("hand", "ik", "L")):
        item.name=item.name + "_something_added_to_the_name"
```

There are many ways to modify strings in Python and you can find out about them searching the web or even resources I linked to above.

Comment: Ok I've ran into an issue. It's basically renaming other things such as widgets and bones which I don't want to be renamed. I'm thinking of a couple work arounds for this but I don't know how to put that into code. The best of these I think would be to somehow have it only search through bones I currently have selected that way it'll avoid all the unwanted things from being renamed. Another way would be to just search through bones and not widgets (as I think I could use not statements and stuff for the unwanted bones but I'm unsure). The problem is the .001 that appears on duplicates